# How to reconfigure default lifecycle mapping in eclipse for maven-compiler-plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I would like to invoke the basic *maven-compiler-plugin* after I modified some java classes in eclipse using default life cycle mappings and *runOnIncremental* while the Java Builder of eclipse is still active.

The reason for this is a combination of OSGi bundle development (maven-scr-plugin) with post-compilation modifications and automatic code replacement using JRebel to speed-up software developing.

```
<lifecycleMappingMetadata>
  <pluginExecutions>

...   

    <pluginExecution>
      <pluginExecutionFilter>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <versionRange>3.1</versionRange>
        <goals> 
          <goal>compiler:compile</goal>
        </goals>
      </pluginExecutionFilter>
      <action>
        <execute>
          <runOnIncremental>true</runOnIncremental>
        </execute>
      </action>
    </pluginExecution>

...

  </pluginExecutions>
</lifecycleMappingMetadata>
```

Unfortunately, this plugin execution mapping is ignored by eclipse, while others are working correctly.

Note: Changing the goal to "compile" changes nothing.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Andy

Comment: For some reason most examples I've found use a goal named `process` for the compiler plugin in this situation, even if the plugin documentation does not list that goal. It did work for me though.

Comment: This does not solve the problem for me, it is still not compiling the modified class.